# Injective function from a set of $n$ element to a set of $n$ element

Tags: functions

How to determine number of Injective function from a set of $n$ element to a set of $n$ element and number of onto function on the same set to itself?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Judging by your answers and rep, you seem like a capable mathematician. I'm curious to know why you couldn't figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may as well assume that the set of $n$ elements is $S = \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$.

Then a mapping $f:S \to S$ can be represented by the sequence of values $T=\big(f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(n)\big)$. If the mapping is injective, it means there are no repetitions in the sequence $T$, so $T$ is just a permutation of $S$. The number of such permutations is $n!$.

If the mapping $f$ is onto, then the sequence $T$ contains every element of $S$, so it's again a permutation of $S$. So the answer is again $n!$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first element you have $n$ possibilities for the second $n-1$ (it can not go to the same element, because of injectivity) etc. So you will get $n!$ different functions.

Comment: In other words, it is the same as the number of bijections, i.e. permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.